# What is this cordova build error \ip-regex\index.js:3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-cordova

I uninstalled Visual Studio 2017 because so many issues trying to build a blank cordova app. I installed VS2015 expecting its better for it. But Im still getting error about this js script that saying a syntax error.
[image]

This is my environment variables, Ive installed 32 bit git manually and the java 32 bit sdk.
[image]

Can anybody please tell me what am I doing wrong setting cordova for visual studio 2015?

Here is the final close up error Im getting just building a newly created cordova project.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just got the same problem. I know it was some time ago, but maybe someone will save time:

The library ip-regex have no fixed version and latest is not compatible.
You should change content of index.js with older version e.g.: https://github.com/sindresorhus/ip-regex/blob/9b6153933a856153fe2ca78081f8851761f03b6c/index.js

Or replace version in package configuration.

Comment: I just gave up on visual studio as its install its own versions of all dependencies in its own folder and just hard to try to fix any issues that will arise. And not a lot of documentation around. I just went cordova full on using VSCode and it is so much better.